# Why is permission needed for geocode/reverse-geocode on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I don't need the user's current location, but I need to translate coordinates into addresses and addresses into coordinates.

I am supposing that you can get the same result without the user granting permission by fetching the same information from a third-party service. You pass them either the coordinates or an address for their corresponding location values. There doesn't seem to be any privacy benefits since having access to a gecode & reverse-geocode service doesn't expose the user.

What is the reason that permission is needed for this service?

**Additional info:**
I am using [Expo 26 (Expo.Location)](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v27.0.0/sdk/location) on Nexus 6P

Comment: What permission does it need?

Comment: `Expo.Permissions.LOCATION`. I am not sure which Android permissions this corresponds to, but it might be  `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the reason it requires that permission is because they didn't think someone would need to do geocoding but not access the users location, so they put both functionality in one class, and put that behind a permissions wall.

But all its really doing is calling an API anyways, so if you don't want to have to ask your users for Location permissions, just call that API yourself directly.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start